# How to copy and combine value of multiple input fields into one single field automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to copy & combine values of `lname`, `fname` & `mname` into `fullname` automatically when I click the `fullname` field.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" onclick="namefunc()">
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function namefunc() {
            var n1 = $('#fname');
            var n2 = $('#mname');
            var n3 = $('#lname');
            var fn = $('#fullname');
            fn.val(n1.val() + " " + n2.val() + " " + n3.val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Its not working. Please help!

Comment: Your function doesn't need to be in the doc ready handler, it can go directly inside the script tags.  Your code should work otherwise. Do you see any errors logged in the console?

Comment: @Nicolay Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nicolay said in the comment, my function doesn't need to be in the doc ready handler, it can go directly inside the script tags. I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function namefunc() {
    var n1 = $('#fname');
    var n2 = $('#mname');
    var n3 = $('#lname');
    var fn = $('#fullname');
    fn.val(n1.val() + " " + n2.val() + " " + n3.val());
  };
</script>
```

And it worked! :)